# Map marker on d3 node

Tags: d3.js

[image]

Need to add a Map maker on the d3 nodes like this. 
This is edited image.

```
nodeEnter
  .append("img")
  .attr("src","https://lh4.ggpht.com/Tr5sntMif9qOPrKV_UVl7K8A_V3xQDgA7Sw_qweLUFlg76d_vGFA7q1xIKZ6IcmeGqg=w300");
```

I tried like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pkolanda/2ryu34qv/). when i did inspect with firebug. i could see the img tag. but map maker was not seen on the nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this
Add the image url inside your data like this:

```
 "nodes": [
    {
      "type": "S",
      "id": "1",
      "name": "100",
            "img":"https://lh4.ggpht.com/Tr5sntMif9qOPrKV_UVl7K8A_V3xQDgA7Sw_qweLUFlg76d_vGFA7q1xIKZ6IcmeGqg=w300"
    },
```

To the node add image like this:

```
nodeEnter
    .append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.img; })
  .attr("x", "-12px")
  .attr("y", "-44px")
  .attr("width", "24px")
  .attr("height", "24px");

  ;
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2ryu34qv/2/)

Hope this helps!